# error when loading a saved game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've create a puzzle game yesterday and I've made a save system, but I'm getting an error when loading the save:

[here's the website](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByBwY60ZsbQpfm01MzBKOHRqWDJhbGxVTjdSRHF0ZE9MYWFsdTg2REVkR3BSNlkzS3BuQkk/)

[and here's a save](http://pastebin.com/k6k97LRu)

here's the function that gets launched when loading a save:

```
function loadSave(){
    var saveData = $("#saveText").text();
    var pieceData = saveData.split("|");
    var posData = [];

    var puzzleInfo = pieceData[0].split(",");
    createGrid(parseInt(puzzleInfo[1]));
    createPieces(parseInt(puzzleInfo[1]), puzzleInfo[0]);

    oldSource = imgSource;
    imgSource = puzzleInfo[0];
    console.log(saveData);
    $("#puzzleContainer img").attr("src", imgSource);

    for(i=1; i < pieceAmount+1; i++){
        posData = pieceData[i].split(";");
        $(".piece:nth-child("+i+")").css({
            top: posData[0],
            left: posData[1],
        });
    }

    $( "#pieceAmount" ).slider({
        value: puzzleInfo[1],
    });
    $("#pieceAmountValue").html(puzzleInfo[1]*puzzleInfo[1]);
}
```

after a bit of troubleshooting, I've found out that puzzleInfo[0] as nothing in it

does anybody knows why the src I'm getting from the save is empty?

edit:

here's the function that launches when an error is detected:

```
$("#puzzleContainer img").error(function(){
    imgSource = oldSource;
    createGrid(Size);
    createPieces(Size, imgSource);
    $("#puzzleContainer img").attr("src", imgSource);
    alert("the image could not be found, is your link correct?");
});
```

Comment: Do you have any event listeners set on the puzzleContainer img element?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @Juhana I've added the function that launches when an error is detected, (it's not an error in the console)

Comment: @Bobulous I do not (unless the .error() event counts as one)

Comment: Yes, the `error` event counts as an event listener. When the first attempt to change the `src` value fails, `error` is firing and trying to change the `src` value. Then that fails, so `error` is called again, and round and round you go.

Comment: @Bobulous I've update the code, the error no longer goes into an infinite loop, I'm still getting the error though

Comment: @Bobulous I've done more troubleshooting and I've made it so that the console shows the source it's trying to load, turns out the source is completely empty, I don't know why

Comment: puzzleInfo[0] is getting correct img src, maybe you are calling load function before dom ready, call your function on $(document).ready(function(){loadSave();})

Comment: I think I've found the core of the problem, the text in savedata is empty even when copying something in the textarea

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out what was wrong

the problem was here:

```
var saveData = $("#saveText").text();
```

saveData was always empty, I needed to get the value using

```
var saveData = $("#saveText").val();
```

instead